# JavaScript to change a character to lowercase in an all uppercase string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a website for a business called iDev Solutions. Throughout the site, headings have been set to uppercase via CSS.

For cases where I mention "iDEV" on a heading, I'd like to find a way to text-transform the "i" to lowercase programmatically.

Is there a JavaScript/jQuery way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  How about simply using jQuery to remove the `text-transform` styling?  Or add a class with `text-transform: none`?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can search for this text in all headings, wrap this text and add a styling.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a variable you can use it.

```
<span>{assign "find" array('A','B','C','Ç','D','E','F','G','Ğ','H','İ','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','Ö','P','R','S','Ş','T','U','Ü','V','Y','Z','ç','ğ','ı','ö','ş','ü',' ')}{assign "repl" array('a','b','c','c','d','e','f','g','g','h','i','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','o','p','r','s','s','t','u','u','v','y','z','c','g','i','o','s','u','')}{$T.TITLE|replace:$find:$repl}</span>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlSZ9.png